# Adding Markers on Google maps using Latitude and Longitude Values from MySQL Database

Tags: javascript, mysql

Here I have tried code from following link to display a marker on map.. its worked..
Now i want to add marker which  retrieves latitude and longitude values from MySQL database and display markers on map... can any one please help me in doing this

http://www.searchengineknowledge.com/hosting/embedgooglemaps.php

Comment: Which other Server side technology you are using..??..like django-python, java etc

Comment: wamp.. php is using to retrive values from data base

Answer (score 0):

See this :

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax.html

Comment: getting errors while doing that... error is all about domxml file that is not resolved..

Comment: php has a domxml function..!!..Read this line : " try initializing a domxml_new_doc() to determine if your server's PHP has dom_xml functionality on"

Comment: yes i have checked that also dom/xml functionality is enabled on my server

Comment: i think you should look at this link : http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/domxml.html

Comment: Here is the error i am getting Fatal error: Class 'domxml_new_doc' not found in C:\wamp\www\myfirstsample\genxml.php on line 6

Comment: you can see the requirements at : http://de3.php.net/manual/en/domxml.requirements.php ........ This extension makes use of the » GNOME XML library. Download and install this library. You will need at least libxml-2.4.14. To use DOM XSLT features you can use the » libxslt library and EXSLT enhancements from » http://www.exslt.org/. Download and install these libraries if you plan to use (enhanced) XSLT features. You will need at least libxslt-1.0.18.

Comment: thank u.. i have tried to install that but didnot get that one so i want to connect php to java script.. so please suggest some javascript functions which takes values from php and can be used in java script